# Need an specefic order of the targets in the Makefile

Tags: makefile

I have a problem, first of all, I'll show you my makefile:

```
CC      = gcc 
CFLAGS  = -Wall -c

all: tarea1 libdisplay.a

tarea1: tarea1.o operations.o -ldisplay -lmatrix
    $(CC) -o $@ $^

tarea1.o: tarea1.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

operations.o: operations.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^

libdisplay.a: display.o
    ar -rcs $@ $^ 

display.o: display.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $^
```

tarea1 is my program, this target need operations.o, it uses libmatrix.a which is given by the professor, but the library libdisplay.a need to be made for me and here is where I have the problem, when I run my makefile it say this:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `-ldisplay', needed by `tarea1'.  Stop.
```

I know that this message appear because it tries to do tarea1 before libdisplay.a exist, so my question is how can I say explicitly that the target libdisplay.a need to be made before tarea1?

Comment: That isn't what that message means. That message is from make not from your compiler. Look at it again. It is saying that make doesn't know how to build a target with that name. See my answer for more detail.

Answer (score 1):

`-ldisplay` is a linker argument not a makefile dependency.

You want `libdisplay.a` on the right-hand side of that `tarea1: ...` line to tell make that that file needs to be created first.